# How to join multiple nearest neighbouring nodes using postgresql or python?

Tags: python, postgresql

I have many short paths SHP file  which look like a longer dashed path.
Is there an efficient way to connect these paths to one continuous path? 
If possible, I want to avoid a hundred times manually selecting 2 nodes pairwise and joining them. And the distance between all the lines are not same

[image]

Comment: If can use PyQGIS - this might help you: https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeometry.html#extend-lines Also you could try to convert them into points and then use this tool: https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorcreation.html#points-to-path

Comment: Thank you for reply but i am looking for something using postgis or python